# OAuth : How to get email address from external provider (GitHub)?

Tags: asp.net, github, asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin

Users on my website can be authenticated through external providers such as GitHub. The process is working well after this call

```
Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, AuthenticationProvider)
```

But one point is that GitHub doesn't return email address.

After the call above, it generates an authorize url with `scope=user`. Maybe this is the point. I think it should work if `scope=user,user:email` as mentioned [there](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes)

I tried to add parameters to `properties` but no luck. Can anyone help me on this, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But one point is that GitHub doesn't return email address.

This might be affected by user's settings on GitHub. There is an option **Settings / Profile / Public email**, if user chooses to public an email it will visible to your app like bellow the claim #3

[image]